# how to define 'App' statement in firestore database?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

I have to define 'app' inorder to store user details from dialogflow to  firestore database

```
const app = new App({request:request, response:response});
```

inorder to use this line of code i need 'App' to be defined in firestore code,for which i have used this line,

```
const App = require('firebase-functions').DialogflowApp;
```

which throws me error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DialogflowApp` isn't defined in firebase-functions. It is defined in the [deprecated version of the actions-on-google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/tree/v1) library.

If you are just getting started with Actions on Google, you should **not** be using this library.

Instead, you should use the [latest version](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) (v2), which handles this slightly differently.

It is also different than a Firebase/Firestore "app". Firebase uses their "app" to communicate with the Firebase system.

You don't need to call either of them "app".

Comment: Then how it is possible to get details entered in dialogflowbot and to store them in database?Do assigning a value to the field declared in firestore work? like --->var name = request.body.result.parameters.name;    will be assigned to a field name in firestore like ---> name: request.body.result.name, Will this really work?

Comment: Try it and see if it works the way you think it does. {: If not, I would say to create a new question with as much of the code to illustrate what you're doing and what isn't working. Showing code fragments in comments are very difficult to work with.